# Running JS from cron-job.org

Tags: javascript, cron

I have a JS that I want to run with a frequency.

I have registered on the page cron-job.org. Thanks for making the page free! But: there is no user manual, so I am a bit stuck...

I´m able to run php-scripts from cron-job.org, but haven´t succeeded in running JS. Any ideas on how to do this on cron-job.org or any tips of a free cron-service with JS-support?

Answer (score 3):

From what I see on their site all they do is visit a URL that you provide.

So, you'll have to create a URL which executes that javascript code you want.

With the help of [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/) you can execute javascript on server-side

Comment: Thanks a lot! Guess this is a good time for me to learn nodejs then :-)

Comment: I this is what guided in the right direction, please accept my answer as the solution :)